# How to integrate Windows.UI.Composition animations into UWP MVVM Light app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mvvm-light

I’m utilizing the Windows.UI.Composition framework for the first time in my app. My app is built on MVVM Light. I'm updating the app to add more transition animations between elements.

The prevailing wisdom with MVVM is that you should keep your UI code in XAML as much as possible, binding visual states to the ViewModel properties, etc. But all of the Windows.UI.Composition material and samples I’ve been seeing, define the UI manipulations in the code-behind instead.

Let’s use a show/hide scenario as an example. I have a bool property in my ViewModel like `ShowTheBox`. I bind TheBox’s Visibility property to the ViewModel property. The Box will show or hide automatically based on changes in my ViewModel.

Now, using Windows.UI.Composition, I want to add fade-in/fadeout animations to the visibility changes of TheBox. Where is the best place to put that C# code and how do I bind that transition to my `ShowTheBox` property?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't agree that point of MVVM is to keep UI code in XAML exclusively. The point of MVVM, as any other layer separation pattern, is to separate UI layer from app's logic. MVVM just adds its own flavors in form of bindings.

So I think that when you have complex animations and other UI related stuff, it's perfectly fine to put them in code-behind. But before doing that, you might want to try to extract as much of your animations as you can to custom controls which will facilitate your doubts a little.

**EDIT:**
Making a lot of your UI logic bound directly to ViewModel properties isn't always a good solution. Layer separation exists for a reason, so when you compose your layers, imaging that you're writing a Xamarin app and have common ViewModels, but different Views for different platforms. Now you're not even sure if on another platform is gonna have those animations or not. Maybe a flow that takes one screen on UWP will take two screens on iOS, or something else. To have a property "IsVisible" which serves only for one of many views isn't making much sense now, does it? So you have to find some common denomination for ViewModel and move everything else to UI layers.

At the end of the day, MVVM is just a pattern which helps you write a better code. It's understandable to want to stick to all the good practices as much as possible, but if it doesn't make sense for your app - is it worth it?

Comment: That all makes sense, but regardless of the code being in the code-behind or not, I don't get how I move from a simple show/hide scenario based on my ViewModel property bound to Visibility (like I described) to a fade in/out animation. It seems like having to create a custom control every time I want to simply fade something in/out would be overkill.

Comment: Well, I guess you're screwed and there are no animations possible in the brutal MVVM world :)  On a serious note, check my updated answer. I hope it helps a little.

Comment: Not everyone has the luxury of picking their framework. Worth it or not I'm stuck with a MVVM Light app. My example wasn't a very good one. My ViewModel doesn't actually contain UI info, it reflects different states of the data. Various UI elements are bound to states of the data via the VM. This works fine for simple visibility. The issue I'm having is how I integrate transition animations into the visibility of elements to make the UI more elegant. I've tried XAML Transitions, but they only play once when an element is created. It's not clear to me how to have these triggered by visibility.

Comment: Yes, I understand difficulties you face. To everything above I can also add that if you need to bound elements look to states of data in VM, you might find this useful: [EnumStateBehavior](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/07/29/a-behavior-to-handle-visualstate-in-universal-apps-with-mvvm/). I think you can try to integrate composition animations here using events of the storyboards in visual states, or find another way. Good luck.